# Dynamically create android layout or menu from a JSON string

Tags: android, xml, json, layout, android-layout

Would it be possible to on app start send a request to a server which would return JSON.  The JSON would contain something like:

```
{
“option”: [
    { “id”: “1”,  “text”: “menuoption1” , “page”:”page1” },
    { “id”: “2”,  “text”:  “menuoption2”, “page”:”page2 “ },
    { “id”: “3”,  “text”:  “menuoption3” , “page”:”page3” },
    { “id”: “4”,  “text”:  “menuoption4” , “page”:”page4” },
],
```

The application would then parse this and create a menu from it? Would I somehow send this to an xml file to dynamically create the layout?

EDIT: Just brainstorm a bit with me...but I suppose for the various "menu objects" created I could create custom view classes which I then populate with the returned json and then add programmatically to the layout?

Comment: I don't think an xml file, but I suppose you could programmatically generate the whole thing... which would be an enormous pain.

Comment: Anything is possible. What is the layout for? Mobile website? or Android App?

Comment: Currently an android app

Comment: Correct - loop over your total JSON objects, creating objects as you go, and inflating them in your view.

Comment: you can check out https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus if it satisfies your use case. You can create views from data dynamically by defining the layout in json itself.